# How to draw a Pascal's triangle?

Tags: math-mode

How to draw a Pascal's triangle, similar to what follows?[image]

Comment: Could you show some code that you've tried? Starting from scratch ain't much fun...

Comment: search for `Pascal triangle` and you'll get what you want. What a surprise ... ;-)